# NVARCHAR2 is being represented as hex

Tags: php, string, oracle, hex, nvarchar

I have an [`NVARCHAR2`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1828) field in Oracle and I'm doing a [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) and appending some text to it.

```sql
LISTAGG(
  CASE
    WHEN a.is_dead = 'Y' AND a.death_cause IS NOT NULL AND a.death_date IS NOT NULL THEN a.composite_pednum || ' - ' || a.death_cause || ' (' || a.death_date || ')'
    WHEN a.is_dead = 'Y' AND a.death_cause IS NOT NULL THEN a.composite_pednum || ' - ' || a.death_cause
    WHEN a.is_dead = 'Y' THEN a.composite_pednum || ' - Dead'
    WHEN a.is_dead = 'N' THEN a.composite_pednum || ' - Alive'
    ELSE a.composite_pednum || ' - Unknown Status'
  END,
  ';'
) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.pedigree_number ASC) AS cage_animals
```

In PHP, I [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) this text to turn it into an array for processing later.

```php
$cage_animals = array();
if(!empty($data['CAGE_ANIMALS'][$i])) {
  $cage_animals = explode(';', $data['CAGE_ANIMALS'][$i]);
}
```

Which gives me something like

```
["cage_animals"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(38) "R15-57713-B - Alive"
    [1]=>
    string(40) "R15-57714-RR - Alive"
  }
```

Notice how the length of the string looks more than it actually is? I think this might be because of the following screenshot *(not the full screenshot)*:

[image]

So my question is how do I prevent this? I'm trying to find the [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) of `Alive` and I always get `false` because the text isn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using either `CAST` or `TO_CHAR` for each of my `THEN` clause.

```sql
LISTAGG(
  CASE
    WHEN a.is_dead = 'Y' AND a.death_cause IS NOT NULL AND a.death_date IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR(a.composite_pednum || ' - ' || a.death_cause || ' (' || TO_CHAR(a.death_date, 'Mon DD, YYYY') || ')')
    WHEN a.is_dead = 'Y' AND a.death_cause IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR(a.composite_pednum || ' - ' || a.death_cause)
    WHEN a.is_dead = 'Y' THEN TO_CHAR(a.composite_pednum || ' - Dead')
    WHEN a.is_dead = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(a.composite_pednum || ' - Alive')
    ELSE TO_CHAR(a.composite_pednum || ' - Unknown Status')
  END,
  ';'
) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.pedigree_number ASC) AS cage_animals
```